# UICollectionView with section-specific layouts and sticky headers

Tags: objective-c

I'm building a UICollectionView with two sections. Each section has its own layout - the first section is a 2-by-y grid and the second section is a 3-by-y grid. In addition to section-specific layouts, I need sticky headers (such as those incorporated by default into UITableViews).

I have already built a fully functional subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout that handles section-specific layouts and sticky headers appropriately. However, the solution doesn't scale well past 250+ cells in either section. I did some profiling and investigation, and the root of the problem seems to be `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange`. I return `YES` in my subclass because of the need for dynamic calculation of my supplementary views (the headers) as the user scrolls. This causes invalidation of both supplementary view and cell layouts, meaning that the flow layout calls `prepareLayout` on the cells over and over despite the fact that the cell layouts don't actually require invalidation as they aren't changing. When the number of cells requiring layout every refresh cycle creeps into the hundreds or thousands, performance drops significantly.

**What I've Tried**

I cache the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` for the cells upon first calculation, allowing the flow layout to reference the cache when the system calls `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`. The advantage of caching in this way flies out the window when I'm constantly invalidating the layout, as `prepareLayout` runs it back and repopulates the cache every time. I tried implementing a system in which `prepareLayout` would only populate the cache on the first pass and execute no logic on subsequent passes. This dramatically improved performance, and worked, but the solution breaks down when inserting and deleting cells, causing an assertion failure.

I've also done a significant amount of research into other implementations of sticky headers and similar layout requirements involving consistent invalidation, but none of these solutions need to simultaneously tackle the section-specific layout problem that I have. As a result, their recommended solutions aren't feasible. I'm a bit out of my depths on this one...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in implementing something similar, here's the solution I arrived at. This solution avoids the need to default `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange` to `YES`, saving a ton of CPU overhead, while keeping the sticky headers intact.

I manually added my headers as subviews of `self.collectionView` and wrote a method to track `self.collectionView.contentOffset.y` to float and stick the headers appropriately as content scrolls. The one caveat of this solution is that it doesn't scale well to larger numbers of sections; by adding the views manually, you lose some benefits of `UICollectionReusableView` such as dequeuing and recycling. In my implementation there are a maximum of 5 sections, so the sacrifice was minimal.